# Attempting to generate buttons in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, button

I have recently been learning WinForms and found a couple tutorials that demonstrate how to generate buttons. However, although it clearly works in the videos I am watching, I am not seeing the buttons appear when the form loads. I am wondering if the is something obvious that I am missing.

---

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = "Connect";
            btn.Name = "Connect";
            btn.Size = new Size(140, 23);
            btn.Location = new Point(0, 137);
            btn.Click += (obj, eArgs) =>
            {

            };
            this.Controls.Add(btn);
            Button btn2 = new Button();
            btn2.Text = "Clear";
            btn2.Name = "Clear";
            btn2.Size = new Size(140, 23);
            btn2.Location = new Point(0, 160);
            btn2.Click += (obj, eArgs) =>
            {

            };
            this.Controls.Add(btn2);


        }
```

---

Comment: Have you bind the Form.Load event?. Bind Form's Load event on the constructor.. this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the Button's location is within view of the window?

What happens if you add these Asserts:

```
Debug.Assert(this.button1.Location.X + this.button1.Size.Height < this.Height);
Debug.Assert(this.button1.Location.Y + this.button1.Size.Width < this.Width);
```

I tried the following minimum code, and the button appeared at position 0,0

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

If you use a visual studio forms project, it is usually easier to do use the designer to add your buttons. Simply drag and drop a button from the toolbox to approximately the location that you want. Use the properties window to change the property values.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

If you look in InitializeComponent you will find code similar to yours:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();

    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // button1
    // 
    this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(58, 58);
    this.button1.Name = "button1";
    this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.button1.Text = "button1";
    this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

    this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
```

The only differences are the `UseVisualStyleBackColor` and the added property. But my program at the top shows that they are not needed for this.

By the way, apart from using the designer to create your buttons, it is usually better to construct all components in the constructor, even though you don't want to show them right now. Just set property `Visible` to false.

If you create all components in the constructor, you can be certain that the button exists throughout your window lifetime.
You never have to check if the event that creates the button (in your
case form load) has been handled already.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to you did not register for the Form1_Load event. There are three ways to solve this problem. The third method is the most widely used.

1. Manually register the Load event for the form in Form.cs.
   As follows:

   ```
   public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.Load+=new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
     }
   ```
2. The Load event is the default event of the form. You can directly double-click the form. In this way, the designer automatically generates a Form_Load event without manual registration. Just add your code in it.
3. In addition, you can also create event handlers on the Windows Form Designer. Understanding this part will be very helpful for you to learn Winform.[To create an event handler on the Windows Forms designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/zwwsdtbk(v=vs.100)#to-create-an-event-handler-on-the-windows-forms-designer)

[image: here]